# sqlite syntax error when updating with string value Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
public class Profile implements Parcelable {

public final static String ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME = "accounts";
public final static String FIELD_DISPLAY_NAME = "displayname";
public final static String FIELD_IP = "ipaddress";
}



String f1 = "planet";
String ip = "udp:85.59.123.78:289";
```

My update query is like below

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Profile.ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + SipProfile.FIELD_IP+ "="+ip +" WHERE "+ Profile.FIELD_DISPLAY_NAME + "=" + f1);
```

i am  getting below error

03-14 09:28:59.720: E/SQLiteLog(13321): (1) near ":85": syntax error

Comment: Well, first, you're using concatenation to create SQL and are therefore quite possibly risking injection attacks and so on. But besides that, you aren't quote-delimiting the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, in where clause ip and f1 values should be in single quotes

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Profile.ACCOUNTS_TABLE_NAME + " SET " + SipProfile.FIELD_IP+ "='"+ip +"' WHERE "+ Profile.FIELD_DISPLAY_NAME + "='" + f1+"'");
```